# Recursive query in db2

Tags: sql, recursion, db2

I am having a problem with recursive query and I can not solve. 
The problem is this: I want to get the tree of customer accounts of a business in the following table:

```
 header table: accounts {id,code,account,dad_id}
id is PK and dad_id is FK references id
    {1,1,'property',null}
    {2,2,'for result',null}
    {3,1,'actives',1}
    {4,2,'passives'1}
    {5,1,'not attributable active',3 }
```

my recursive sql and my problem for built the tree.

```
WITH TEMP(id,code,account,dad_id) AS(
 SELECT id,code,account,dad_id 
 FROM FINAL.ACCOUNT a
 WHERE a.dad_id IS NOT  NULL 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT a.id,a.code,a.account,t.dad_id
 FROM FINAL.ACCOUNT a, TEMP t
 WHERE a.dad_id=t.dad_id
)
select * from TEMP;
```

Expected result
 code

```
1.0 property
 1.1 Actives 
   1.1.1 Non atribbutable active 
 1.2 Passive 
2.0 for result
```

from already thank you very much for reading, I'm open to all answers 
thanks

Comment: An excellent source for recursive queries is here: http://www.idug-db2.com?commid=105565

Comment: Given the accounts table in your example, what is the expected result ?

Comment: You're joining `a.dad_id` to `t.dad_id`, you're joing rows to all siblings **plus itself** - you have no termination condition, the result rows should grow exponentially, and the server should be throwing an error of some sort (or possibly flat-out refusing to run it).  You (usually) can't actually start with `WHERE <parent_id> IS NULL`, as you'll end up including some rows multiple times; whatever your start condition is, those rows should only be included _once_.

Comment: thanks all for answer , my expected  result is 
code
1.0 property
  1.1 Actives
    1.1.1 Non atribbutable active
  1.2 Passive
2.0 for result